# AWS Cognito Android - Internal error on verifyAttribute api call

Tags: android, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I have successfully integrated the AWS Cognito functions in android app with help of `compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider:2.4.6'`

SignUp and Login functions are working fine, but when I try to verify `phone_number` attribute then it gives `Internal error`.

What I have done

Step 1: getting verification code for `phone_number` attribute

```
user.getAttributeVerificationCodeInBackground("phone_number", new VerificationHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(CognitoUserCodeDeliveryDetails verificationCodeDeliveryMedium) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
                LogHelper.printErrorLog(dataManager.formatException(exception));
            }
        });
```

and I am getting the verification code in my mobile as sms with 6 digit code.

Step 2: Submitting the verification code

```
user.verifyAttribute("phone_number", verificationCode, new GenericHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {

            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
                LogHelper.printErrorLog(dataManager.formatException(exception));
                // here i am getting Internal Error
            }
        });
```

## UPDATE

AWS Request ID: c41d7648-8891-11e7-9fa1-7762eecd6b9a

Region : N.Virginia (US East-1)

[image]

Comment: am having the same issue ,please inform anyone get answer.

Comment: Please post the exception, I work for Cognito, and in the logs i don't see any "VerifyUserAttribute" call for this userPool

Comment: @VasileiosLekakis I got the solution, it was not issue with the api call,i am calling the verify attribute api in the main thread and the

Comment: and getting the NetworkOnMainThread Exeption,but the formatException() helper function returns "Internal Error" as a error message.It was my fault. Anyway thank u for your help.

Comment: great, I'm glad you found it